# iOS Build does not show up when submitting an app for a review in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I uploaded the app successfully via Xcode to App Store Connect. This is not the first time when I'm pushing out an update or an App, I followed the same steps I did in my previous apps/updates. I archived -> validated and distributed.

The app build shows up in App Store Versions under Activity as `Prepare for Submission` but it doesn't show up in the Build section under the AppStore tab.

I have searched this error and most of the folks got an email with some bug or missing file required in the binary. But I haven't received anything in the email associated with this account.

Comment: Facing the same issue since yesterday. Build is shown as prepare for submission but the build section does not show builds. Feels like stuck up. One of my friends who is iOS developer is also facing same issue.

I just checked mailbox but no such email with missing file is received.

Comment: @Nikhil Yep, it's been 24 hours for me as well. Please do keep me in the loop, if you make any progress. Cheers.

Comment: Happening for about a week now. Some builds show up instantly, other take >12 hrs. Uploading multiple builds sometimes helped

Comment: @Max it took me easily more than 36hrs for the first build to show up. I didn't upload the multiple builds as I didn't know what the issue was, but yeah there seems to be some issues lately.